# Softkey not showing all the button on Android Emulator after update

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-softkeyboard

Before updating Eclipse Android plugin and SDK manager when I was create new emulator then it show lot of button on softkey.
And after updating when I create new emulator then it show few button on softkey...

**Before Updating :-**

[image]

**After Updating :-**

[image]

how to get emulator with all the button as softkey?

Comment: Does it affects your development in any way...

Comment: no it not effect ...but the previous one give classic look...and you have more option to enter character...

Comment: yeah, but to most those extra buttons are of rare use and are almost redundant. We can work without them.. Hence, for simplicity removed....